# Android ViewPager - multiple pageChangeListener not working properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a strange problem with ViewPager when im trying to add multiple pageChangleListeners. I have tried looking for a post/question with a similar description but could not find any so here we go:

**short version:** only 1 onPageChangeListener is triggering for the first page, but for the second page multiple listeners are triggering.

**long version:**
in my app i need every ViewPager to have multiple OnPageChangeListeners. even though i couldn't find any confirmation on this in the android documentation, the name of the function "addOnPageChangeListener" suggests that i can have multiple listeners set to the same ViewPager (especially because it used to be "**set**PageChangeListener" and they changed it to "**add**PageChangeListener"). Now, i have some code that needs to run every time a page is selected in any ViewPager in my app so i made my own ViewPager and OnPageChangeListener classes:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager
{
    private ArrayList<Sequence> mSequenceList;

    public MyViewPager(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter)
    {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        mSequenceList = ((MyPagerAdapter)adapter).getSequences();

        addOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangedListener(mSequenceList));
        Log.i("aaaaa", "added listener from MyViewPager");
    }
}
```

and also i made my own page change listener:

```
public class MyOnPageChangedListener implements MyViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyOnPageChangedListener";

    private ArrayList<Sequence> sequenceList;

    public MyOnPageChangedListener(ArrayList<Sequence> sequenceList)
    {
        this.sequenceList = sequenceList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        Log.i("aaaaa", "selecting page " + position + " from my listener");

        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
```

i also have this in my activity's OnCreate:

```
mPageChangedListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {Log.i("aaaaa", "selecting page " + position + " from activity");
                //do something
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        };

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangedListener);
        Log.i("aaaaa", "added listener from activity");
```

and i use this in my activity to trigger onPageSelected for the first page

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    mViewPager.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mPageChangedListener.onPageSelected(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
    });
}
```

but when i run the app i get some strange behavior. here is the log output:

```
02-23 03:08:41.192 17147-17147/com.*** I/aaaaa: added listener from MyViewPager
02-23 03:08:41.193 17147-17147/com.*** I/aaaaa: added listener from activity
02-23 03:08:41.273 17147-17147/com.*** I/aaaaa: selecting page 0 from activity
02-23 03:09:03.609 17147-17147/com.*** I/aaaaa: selecting page 1 from my listener
02-23 03:09:03.609 17147-17147/com.*** I/aaaaa: selecting page 1 from activity
```

as you can see both listeners are added, but for the first page (index 0) only the listener from the activity is triggered whereas for the second page (index 1) both listeners are triggered.

this is a major problem for me as my own onPageChangedListener **must be triggered for every single page**.

anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course 1 minute after posting this question i figured it out... i am posting the solution for anyone who may face a similar issue:

the problem lies in the onResume() method of my activity. i noticed that i am only triggering the listener i registered in the activity and not my custom listener. problem is that i don't have access to MyOnPageChangedListenerfrom the activity so what i made it a global variable in MyOnPageChangedListener and added a get method to access it. here is my modified class:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager

{
    private ArrayList<Sequence> mSequenceList;

    private MyOnPageChangedListener mPageChangeListener;

    //making the compiler happy
    public MyViewPager(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    //making the compiler happy
    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter)
    {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        mSequenceList = ((MyPagerAdapter)adapter).getSequences();

        mPageChangeListener = new MyOnPageChangedListener(mSequenceList);
        addOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
        Log.i("aaaaa", "added listener from MyViewPager");
    }

    public MyOnPageChangedListener getMyPageChangeListener()
    {
        return mPageChangeListener;
    }
}
```

and here is my updated onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    //this is to invoke "onPageSelected()" for the first page
    //when the viewpager is first created, and when the activity is resumed
    //(for example when coming back from "edit profile")
    mViewPager.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mViewPager.getMyPageChangeListener()
                      .onPageSelected(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            mPageChangedListener.onPageSelected(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
    });
}
```

however this feels a little like a hack to me as opposed to an elegant solution... also it means that i have to do this manually for every activity where i want to trigger my own listener.

unfortunately there is no such method "getAllPageChangedListeners".

is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling onPageSelected() explicitly only on your mPageChangedListener, it doesn't go through the full cycle of selecting a page, thus not calling the onPageSelected() for all the listeners assigned.
If you look at the ViewPager source, you can see that dispatchOnPageSelected(int position) wont be called if you trigger

```
mPageChangedListener.onPageSelected(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

like you did.

I missed the fact that setCurrentItem(int position) has no effect if the selected item is already selected... so for the initial selection, you should keep an instance of all your listeners and call onPageSelected() on each.
After that, using mViewPager.setCurrentItem(int position) will trigger both (or all) your listeners.

Comment: yeah i noticed that too almost immediately after posting the question lol (see my answer). unfortunately while your solution **should** work, it does not: when i call "setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())" it does not trigger the "onPageSelected" method (in any of the listeners).

Comment: Right, i missed that by default the selected item is 0, thus selecting it again has no effect. Edited the answer, the solution is pretty much your own answer :)